# MongoSwift Pod contains 100 compiler errors. Unable to build after install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mongodb-stitch, xcode10.2

I have an iOS app I am planning on integrating with `MongoDB`. After installing the pod files, upon build I get about 100 errors and I'm not really sure what's causing it or how to fix them.

Added a screenshot of some of the errors. They are all almost exactly the same.

[image]
[image]

I have tried reinstalling the `MongoDB` cocoapod (`pod 'StitchSDK', '~> 5.0.0'`) With the same results.

I'm using Xcode 10.2, set Swift language to 4.0, iOS target build to 11.0 (I may have done these completely wrong though.)

Expecting to be able to build the app with no errors.

Comment: Still need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now use the latest version, StitchSDK 6.0.0.

<strike>You will need to wait for the SDK to be updated. Meanwhile, you can download a [previous version of Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/). You will be able to test iOS apps with iOS 12.1.4, but NOT 12.2 and up</strike>

https://github.com/mongodb/stitch-ios-sdk/issues/156.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Looks like they updated MongoSwift to version '0.1.0'. however now I'm getting the "No such module 'MongoSwift'" error

Comment: MongoDB Stitch still does not work with Xcode above 10.1. You can develop, although not for the latest version of iOS, using Xcode 10.1. Please track this issue on GitHub [stitch-ios-sdk](https://github.com/mongodb/stitch-ios-sdk/issues). There you can check out the latest development.

Comment: Use latest version StitchSDK 6.0.0.